# Laravel post Api used as web routes without csfr token

Tags: php, laravel-5, csrf-protection, laravel-passport

This is my scenario:

We need to use some Laravel API methods in the same web app where they are stored. (I'm using Laravel 5.5)
I have the api routes used by third parts applications with Bearer Token and the worked like a charm.
So, I've created other routes group that doesn't use "api:auth" middleware but the "auth" one (with "web" middleware addition).

**RouteService provider** initialization (method invoked in "map" one):

```
protected function mapWebApiRoutes() {
    Route::prefix('web_api')
        ->middleware('web')
        ->as('web_api.')
        ->namespace($this->namespace."\\API")
        ->group(base_path('routes/web_api.php'));
}
```

**Routes declaration:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ["auth"]], function () {
    // routes....
});
```

So, if i run "php artisan route:list", it outputs routes like:

```
GET|HEAD      | web_api/v1/controller            | web_api.      | ...\API\Controller@index      | web,auth
POST          | web_api/v1/controller/lists      | web_api.      | ...\API\Controller@lists      | web,auth
```

I've added routes to **VerifyCsrfToken** except array:

```
 protected $except = [
    "web_api/*"
];
```

The routes with GET method works as well as they can when the user is logged on our platform (through auth middleware) but the POST routes returns an unauthorized error with this body:

```
{message: "Unauthenticated."}
```

***Question:***

Considering that I have excluded those routes from CSRF verification, somebody could explain to me what that error is caused by?

Comment: In your route you have `middleware' => ["auth"]`, have you provided the credentials for authentification?

Comment: @Nerea: yes, the user is logged in correctly

Comment: Are you using `Auth::user()` in your post method?